# why django not found module psycopg2 in django2.2 and python 3.8

Tags: python, django, psycopg2

I install django 2.2.10 and python 3.8 and psycopg2 2.8.4 but when i try migration with command (python manage.py migrate) confront this error:

raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named 'psycopg2'

psycopg2 in 32-bit. i try any solution that available in stackoverflow but this error don't dissolve

databases in settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'seyyedh',
        'PASSWORD' : '123456',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT' : '5432',
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't think this is the answer but please note that the proper engine name is: `django.db.backends.postgresql`. You should remove the `_psycopg2` part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that psycopg2 installed on another virtual env while main virtual env running 
so I unistalled that virtual env and error solved

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** 
Sorry, I didn't read your config.
If you are using Postgresql, your Engine-Setting should be 'django.db.backends.postgresql', not 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2':

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'seyyedh',
        'PASSWORD' : '123456',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT' : '5432',
    }
}
```

as seen [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#engine). You probably shouldn't use the initial postgres DB (as referenced in "NAME"), but create a new database for your django project.

**Initial answer:**
Are you by chance using another python environment than the one configured for your project?

E.g., if you created a virtual environment for you project and have that configured for running the application etc. in your IDE, but for the migration call you are using the python system environment.

If you open the interactive shell for the python environment you are using for migration, and type:

```
help('modules')
```

psycopg2 has to be listed!

Comment: Do you still get the same error? Did you create a new database and used that instead of the "postgres"-DB?

Answer (score 0):

`pip install psycopg2-binary`

(or)

`pip install psycopg2` for <2.8 psycopg2 versions

(or)

`sudo apt-get install python-psycopg2`